# SQL Server table UPDATE function in a report webpage

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have a "form" in a webpage format. It currently works saving entered data into our db and loading back older reports. I would like to now finish the page with an update function. So if I change a value or add one in an empty cell then it'll reflect the change back in the db table.

```
protected void SaveReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxxxxx;Initial Catalog=Web Forms;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=SA;Password=xxxx");

    SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("insert into BlockReport(Job#, PO#, Supplier, RecievedBy, DateRecieved, OrderedSizeCav, MaterialTypeCav, ActualSizeLCav, ActualSizeWCav, ActualSizeHCav, BlockWeightCav, SteelCertHeat#Cav, SteelCertHardness#Cav, SteelCertTemperingTempCav, Rockwell#RawBlockCav, RawBlockTestedByCav, Rockwell#PostRoughCav, PostRoughTestedByCav, Rockwell#PostStressCav, PostStressTestedByCav, CavityBlockNotes, OrderedSizeCore, MaterialTypeCore, ActualSizeLCore, ActualSizeWCore, ActualSizeHCore, BlockWeightCore, SteelCertHeat#Core, SteelCertRockwell#Core, SteelCertTemperingTempCore, Rockwell#RawBlockCore, RawBlockTestedByCore, Rockwell#PostRoughCore, PostRoughTestedByCore, Rockwell#PostStressCore, PostStressTestedByCore, CoreBlockNotes) values(@JobNumberEntry, @POEntry, @SupplierEntry, @RecByEntry, @DateRecEntry, @CavOrderedSizeEntry, @CavMatTypeEntry, @CavLEntry, @CavWEntry, @CavHEntry, @CavBlockWeightEntry, @CavHeatEntry, @CavHardnessEntry, @CavTemperingTempEntry, @CavRockwellRawEntry, @CavRawTestedByEntry, @CavRockwellPostRoughEntry, @CavPostRoughTestedByEntry, @CavRockwellPostStressEntry, @CavPostStressTestedByEntry, @CavBlockNotesEntry, @CoreOrderedSizeEntry, @CoreMatTypeEntry, @CoreLEntry, @CoreWEntry, @CoreHEntry, @CoreBlockWeightEntry, @CoreHeatEntry, @CoreRockEntry, @CoreTemperingTempEntry, @CoreRockwellRawEntry, @CoreRawTestedByEntry, @CoreRockwellPostRoughEntry, @CorePostRoughTestedByEntry, @CoreRockwellPostStressEntry, @CorePostStressTestedByEntry, @CoreBlockNotesEntry )", conn);

    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobNumberEntry", JobNumberEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@POEntry", POEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupplierEntry", SupplierEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecByEntry", RecByEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateRecEntry", DateRecEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavOrderedSizeEntry", CavOrderedSizeEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavMatTypeEntry", CavMatTypeEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavLEntry", CavLEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavHEntry", CavHEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavWEntry", CavWEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavBlockWeightEntry", CavBlockWeightEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavHeatEntry", CavHeatEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavHardnessEntry", CavHardnessEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavTemperingTempEntry", CavTemperingTempEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavRockwellRawEntry", CavRockwellRawEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavRawTestedByEntry", CavRawTestedByEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavRockwellPostRoughEntry", CavRockwellPostRoughEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavPostRoughTestedByEntry", CavPostRoughTestedByEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavRockwellPostStressEntry", CavRockwellPostStressEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavPostStressTestedByEntry", CavPostStressTestedByEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavBlockNotesEntry", CavBlockNotesEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoreOrderedSizeEntry", CoreOrderedSizeEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoreMatTypeEntry", CoreMatTypeEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoreLEntry", CoreLEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoreHEntry", CoreHEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoreWEntry", CoreWEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoreBlockWeightEntry", CoreBlockWeightEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoreHeatEntry", CoreHeatEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoreRockEntry", CoreRockEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoreTemperingTempEntry", CoreTemperingTempEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoreRockwellRawEntry", CoreRockwellRawEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoreRawTestedByEntry", CoreRawTestedByEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoreRockwellPostRoughEntry", CoreRockwellPostRoughEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CorePostRoughTestedByEntry", CorePostRoughTestedByEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoreRockwellPostStressEntry", CoreRockwellPostStressEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CorePostStressTestedByEntry", CorePostStressTestedByEntry.Text);
    insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoreBlockNotesEntry", CoreBlockNotesEntry.Text);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
}
```

I am not sure if additional info is needed, but I am more than happy to go back and fix it or fill in any blanks. I am not sure if there is a catch all option or if it would be simpler to just add a new "update" button.

I have a chunk of code here that is not working

```
   protected void UpdateReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ITMTNSVRSTS;Initial Catalog=Web Forms;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=SA;Password=agh1n86f");
    SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand("update BlockReport set CoreBlockNotes = @CoreBlockNotesEntry, PO# = @POEntry, Supplier = @SupplierEntry, RecievedBy = @RecByEntry, DateRecieved = @DatRecEntry, OrderedSizeCav = @CavOrderedSizeEntry, MaterialTypeCav = @CavMatTypeEntry, ActualSizeLCav = @CavLEntry, ActualSizeHCav = @CavHEntry, ActualSizeWCav = @CavWEntry, BlockWeightCav = @CavBlockWeightEntry, SteelCertHeat#Cav = @CavHeatEntry, SteelCertHardness#Cav = @CavHardnessEntry, SteelCertTemperingTempCav = @CavTemperingTempEntry, Rockwell#RawBlockCav = @CavRockwellRawEntry, RawBlockTestedByCav = @CavRawTestedByEntry, Rockwell#PostRoughCav = @CavRockwellPostRoughEntry, PostRoughTestedByCav = @CavPostRoughTestedByEntry, Rockwell#PostStressCav = @CavRockwellPostStressEntry, PostStressTestedByCav = @CavPostStressTestedByEntry, CavityBlockNotes = @CavBlockNotesEntry, OrderedSizeCore = @CoreOrderedSizeEntry, MaterialTypeCore = @CoreMatTypeEntry, ActualSizeLCore = @CoreLEntry, ActualSizeHCore = @CoreHEntry, ActualSizeWCore = @CoreWEntry, BlockWeightCore = @CoreBlockWeightEntry, SteelCertHeat#Core = @CoreHeatEntry, SteelCertRockwell#Core = @CoreRockEntry, SteelCertTemperingTempCore = @CoreTemperingTempEntry, Rockwell#RawBlockCore = @CoreRockwellRawEntry, RawBlockTestedByCore = @CoreRawTestedByEntry, Rockwell#PostRoughCore = @CoreRockwellPostRoughEntry, PostRoughTestedByCore = @CorePostRoughTestedByEntry, Rockwell#PostStressCore = @CoreRockwellPostStressEntry, PostStressTestedByCore = @CorePostStressTestedByEntry, CoreBlockNotes = @CoreBlockNotesEntry where Job# = @JobNumberEntry", conn);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobNumberEntry", JobNumberEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@POEntry", POEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupplierEntry", SupplierEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecByEntry", RecByEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateRecEntry", DateRecEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavOrderedSizeEntry", CavOrderedSizeEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavMatTypeEntry", CavMatTypeEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavLEntry", CavLEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavHEntry", CavHEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavWEntry", CavWEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavBlockWeightEntry", CavBlockWeightEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavHeatEntry", CavHeatEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavHardnessEntry", CavHardnessEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavTemperingTempEntry", CavTemperingTempEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavRockwellRawEntry", CavRockwellRawEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavRawTestedByEntry", CavRawTestedByEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavRockwellPostRoughEntry", CavRockwellPostRoughEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavPostRoughTestedByEntry", CavPostRoughTestedByEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavRockwellPostStressEntry", CavRockwellPostStressEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavPostStressTestedByEntry", CavPostStressTestedByEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CavBlockNotesEntry", CavBlockNotesEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoreOrderedSizeEntry", CoreOrderedSizeEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoreMatTypeEntry", CoreMatTypeEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoreLEntry", CoreLEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoreHEntry", CoreHEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoreWEntry", CoreWEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoreBlockWeightEntry", CoreBlockWeightEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoreHeatEntry", CoreHeatEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoreRockEntry", CoreRockEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoreTemperingTempEntry", CoreTemperingTempEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoreRockwellRawEntry", CoreRockwellRawEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoreRawTestedByEntry", CoreRawTestedByEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoreRockwellPostRoughEntry", CoreRockwellPostRoughEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CorePostRoughTestedByEntry", CorePostRoughTestedByEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoreRockwellPostStressEntry", CoreRockwellPostStressEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CorePostStressTestedByEntry", CorePostStressTestedByEntry.Text);
    update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoreBlockNotesEntry", CoreBlockNotesEntry.Text);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        update.ExecuteNonQuery();


    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Thank you, that advice has been given. I am learning as I go so first I just want to get it working. Then I can go back and make a better version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same idea with the update. The only difference you should locate a record in the DB based on the unique id in the table:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
           connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("update BlockReport set Supplier = @SupplierEntry where Job# = @JobNumberEntry", connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobNumberEntry", JobNumberEntry.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupplierEntry", SupplierEntry.Text);

    command.Connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: No that part works. I must have just left that part out. I am looking for help with the UPDATE part of things

Comment: There I added the few lines that execute

Comment: Please, no .AddWithValue. http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications
Here is another
https://andrevdm.blogspot.com/2010/12/parameterised-queriesdont-use.html

Comment: Thank you. I am just barely in the door with any of this ( this is my first actual project since basic html in high school). I am going to try and decipher a few things and try. I will also see if I can post what I have already been trying.

Comment: Mary, it makes a lot of sense when you're doing tons of operations in second and every ms counts. Probably the entire way of doing this should be different then. For a low-load systems AddWithValue works perfectly fine and reliable.

Comment: Thank you Mary. After I get it working on a base level I will look into this and other better ways of doing all of this. I do not think I am very well protected against injection here so I still have some serious work to get done.

Comment: @Elastep the problems with AddWithValue aren't all about performance. It can cause imprecise data when dealing with floats and dates.

Comment: @Elastep maybe did something wrong but got no errors, just didn't work

Comment: @Elastep. Thank you, I pulled my head out of my ass and understood what you were doing. Everything works fine now that I got around the syntax issue. I have been entering all the old reports in the system and updated about 10 of them with no problems